# Unrecognized PORT command

Tags: node.js, windows, command-prompt

In my localhost, running below command

```
PORT=4080 node server.js
```

But, it was throwing an unexpected error.

> 'PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Do I need to install any module or did I miss any syntax to run it properly?

Comment: The above command is Unix (Ubuntu, Mac, etc…). In windows enviroment, you need a different syntax. Google something like "set env in windows command line"

Comment: I configured environment variable for nodeJs, If I run `node server.js`, It was running on port 3000. But I need to run it on port 4030. I thought, I need a module for the port but I didn't find anything related to that in google. I thought it would be useful for others if I raise this as an issue.

Comment: You said you have configured for port 3000, you  an change that configuration to 4080, it should work??

Comment: @Subburaj, It is a default port but I need to change it to 4080. For that configuration, I didn't find any article.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Apart from [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env), Below command can serve the purpose.

```
SET PORT=4080 && node server.js
```

PS: Set environment variable for nodeJs, run command in project folder.

Comment: This would cause your system variables to change, which is not very desirable. `cross-env` solves this.

Comment: Will this work in Linux/MacOS?

Comment: No, it is for windows.

Answer (score 9):

- Install this additional package [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) in your node
  environment. The above command you mentioned is Unix (Ubuntu, Mac,
  etc…). In the windows environment, you need a different syntax and cross-env does your job.
- You can also create an .env file with

```html
PORT=3006
```

and save it in your
   project directory.

Comment: Hey please check my answer and verify it :)

Comment: I suggest going with this solution. Chances are, there will be other variables and you'll be monkey patching this all day long. Leave that to the authors from cross-env.

Answer (score 7):

In Windows you can set scripts in `package.json`:

```json
"start": " set PORT=portnumber && react-app-rewired start"
```

or

```json
"start": " set PORT=3001 && react-script start".
```

It worked for me:

[image: in package.json file]

Comment: Nice one! This worked for me in Windows in VSCode. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`SET PORT=8090 && nodemon server.js` that worked for me

Comment: I need to run port 4080

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: If things dont work out this way, leave it like `nodemon server.js` then in your terminal say `export port=4080` (your choice port of course)
 then `npm nodemon` to start the server

Comment: @Mbanda Thanks for sharing your knowledge, unfortunately, I solved it and not tested with your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Install `cross-env` to support all OS.

```
npm install --save-dev cross-env
or
yarn add -D cross-env
```

And finally add cross-env to your command in `package.json`.

```
cross-env PORT=4080 node server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a moronic way I found to recreate this problem:

1. Create a npm based app on one system
2. check it out on another system
3. FAIL to run `npm install`
4. run `npm start`

Receive error described in question.

Answer (score 0):

automatically run this port :3000,I tried windows working react

```
"devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.8.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Comment: did you even try to read the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way also

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "concurrently \"cd client && npm build\" \"cd server && npm build\"",
    "install": "(cd client && npm) && (cd server && npm)",
    "start": "concurrently \"cd client && SET PORT=3000 && npm start\" \"cd server && SET PORT=3001 && npm start\"",
    "start:prod": "cd server && npm start:prod"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you can set scripts in package.json:

Delete `set PORT=portnumber &&`

and keep it like this :

```js
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Once I realised that the issue is it's a linux command, I switch shells to use Git Bash(I'm using Vs-code) and it worked seamlessly. Hoping this is helpful for a newbie that finds the other suggestions daunting.